# "Can a Stored Procedure in T-SQL have a "SELECT *" statement"?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can a stored procedure in SQL Server contain "Select *" keyword . Shoud'nt it have "Select col name from table name". Is it the correct practice to have "select  *" in a stored procedure specifically in T-SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Can it? Yes.

Should it? Almost certainly not.

The use case for `select *` should be limited to those situations where you want to get every current column, regardless of what gets added or removed from the table at any time in the future.

That's pretty well limited to a few small scenarios such as:

- debugging where you want the entire table output for checking things; or
- tools like table dumpers where you want everything.

I would suggest that every *user* query specifically grab only the columns they need since this both:

- minimises over-the-wire transfers; and
- makes it easy to detect where the DBA has deleted one of your columns without telling you.

Since it makes little sense having non-user queries in stored procedures, you should probably *never* `select *` from them.

Comment: 'select *' is very useful while still building and debugging a query, but it should be fixed before moving the query into a procedure, view, source control, or client code.